# Opencart 1.5.5.1 Error: You don't have permission to access /admin/index.php on this server

Tags: http-status-code-404, opencart, http-status-code-403, vqmod

I have installed opencart 1.5.5.1, and latest VQmod 2.4.1 and Product Video Tab. In my product edit option, i can see Youtube video tab. But when i paste youtube link and try to save, iam getting below error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin/index.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

please help

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you have to add route in the url with index.php, to access that page.

Suppose you have entered '

```
admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&token=594683c55af7002fb0d00f6915f75ca6
```

Then it will go to ,
`admin/controller/common folder`, there you will find `dashboard.php`

and token will be generated when admin login in the admin panel.

If you type admin/index.php , then it will never anywhere.Please insert the url properly.